# my CSS style sheet is not linking to my html

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to link my css style sheet to my html file using the code

```
<link ref="stylesheet" href="../landing/css/stylesheet.css" type="text/css"/>
```

I have checked my directory link and when command clicking on the /landing/css part it takes me to my CSS file

However when I open the file in my browser to preview I cant see any of my CSS styling applying to the file

Thanks for any help in advance

[html code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J4Z9F.png)

[CSS code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pgny2.png)

[browser view when opening file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/31mwY.png)

Comment: As far as I understand your HTML file is in landing folder, so you should change href. `<link ref="stylesheet" href="css/stylesheet.css" type="text/css"/>`

Answer (score 2):

Change the value for href attribute to:
"css/stylesheet.css"
Remove the earlier part as it takes you out of the folder and then back again in. See if this helps, else reply here further

Comment: I've renamed the code to  <link ref="stylesheet" href="css/stylesheet.css" type="text/css"/> I can see on Visual studio code when command clicking href="css/stylesheet.css it is linked but when opening the html file it I'm still unable to see my styling

Answer (score 0):

From what I observe , you have used double dots in your `"href"`

You need to link it like this:

```
<link ref="stylesheet" href="./css/stylesheet.css" type="text/css"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

I am pretty sure that you just have to do css/stylesheet.css. Not sure what the landing part is about

```
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/stylesheet.css">
```

Answer (score 0):

May be you can try this might helpful.

```
<link href="css/stylesheet.css" type="text/css"/>
```

Comment: Thanks I've tried that I've changed the code to  <link href="css/stylesheet.css" type="text/css"/> I can see on Visual studio code when command clicking href="css/stylesheet.css it is linked but when opening the html file it I'm still unable to see my styling